# JQuery mobile dynamic page loading

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have 2 HTML pages, the first is login and then leads to the 2nd page. 
The first time when the app is started the login credentials are taken and stored in database.
The second time app is started it first checks in the database for the credentials (I have put the code of checking the DB in `$(document).ready(function())`). 
If it finds the credentials it should go to the second page, otherwise take the credentials (to the login page). 
But the problem is even if it finds the credentials in DB still the login page just blinks and second page is displayed (the code for loading the second page is written in `$(document).ready(function())`).

I am new to cross platform mobile development and JQuery.